# But why are the two sets of absolute parentheses different sizes?

Tags: amsmath

Silly question maybe - but why are the two sets of absolute different sizes?

Is there an easy way to set the size locally - or globally?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{\underline{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$
I (\theta, \varphi) =
\left |
\vect{E}_{dir}^p(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
+
\vect{E}_{ref}^p(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
\right |^2
+
\left |
\vect{E}_{dir}^s(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
+
\vect{E}_{dir}^s(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
\right |^2
$

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)Can you wrap your code with a simple MWE with your definition of `\vect` or the package loading it?

Comment: I don't see what "absolute different sizes" are you refering to.. I get [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bnfSS.png) (defined `\vect` as `\vec`)

Comment: Also, you should use `\text{dir}`, `\text{ref}` instead of `dir` and `ref`. Note the weird kerning you got in "ref". In math mode a sequence of letters is not considered a word, but instead a product of single-char named variables, hence the odd spacing.

Comment: thanks for the advice.
As for your questions - I redefined the 'vect' command - since I wasn't 100% sure what look I would go for in general (in terms of bold\underline etc - so I figured that if i defined it right at the beginning it would sort it out.

Comment: I added the newcommand...BTW what does MWE stand for?

Comment: @JPH: [MWE is explained in this link](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Basically, you should provide a complete compilable example including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the entire problem, and not just code snippets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get different sizes because of the `f` in the subscript.

There's no need of `\left` and `\right` here; in other words, they are not the best choice here.

I propose two versions, one with normal sized bars (which I prefer), one with slightly bigger ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\tsub}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}
\begin{document}
$
I (\theta, \varphi) = 
\lvert
\vect{E}_\tsub{dir}^p(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
+
\vect{E}_\tsub{ref}^p(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
\rvert^2
+
\lvert 
\vect{E}_\tsub{dir}^s(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
+
\vect{E}_\tsub{dir}^s(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
\rvert^2
$

$
I (\theta, \varphi) = 
\bigl\lvert
\vect{E}_\tsub{dir}^p(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
+
\vect{E}_\tsub{ref}^p(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
\bigr\rvert^2
+
\bigl\lvert 
\vect{E}_\tsub{dir}^s(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
+
\vect{E}_\tsub{dir}^s(\theta, \varphi, r)_{\infty}
\bigr\rvert^2
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice how I realized the textual subscripts; this kind of subscript should go in upright type and `\textnormal` ensures it.